# why no assertAll in Python's unittest

Tags: python-3.x

With some frequency, I find myself using `assertTrue` with `all`.  It seems like it would be nice instead to get an elementwise report of failures, which one might expect from an `assertAll` method.  However this (or an equivalent) seems not to be in `unittest`.  Has it just not been implemented, or has it been ruled out (say, because one may simply `assertTrue` in a loop instead)?

Comment: Why is there no `assertAny`, then? Or `assertExactlyTwo`? Probably because `assertTrue` is generic enough, and all the other variants can be implemented by the programmer with `all`, `any` and whatever function that checks the conditions you need.

Comment: You can always have your own `asset_all` function in your `test_utils` module...

Comment: @ForceBru That cannot be the reason, or all the other assert methods would go away as well.